# Can GTMLogger get the stderr as input?

Tags: objective-c, logging, stdout, stderr

I am trying to embed the GTMLogger in my app to log all information. My app uses a 3rd party code that logs events to stderr and stdout. I have redirected those to my app's stderr and would like to print those to the log file. Is it naively possible to do that? Can someone help me by giving an example of how its done? I am a newbe to objc so pardon my ignorance :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up redircting standard output and standard error to my stderr, opened a GTMLogger object and set the writer to my stderr. 
Then using freopen I printed the stderr to the desired log file.